# How to change value to an input field of type file using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I have an input field of type file and i want to change its value using jquery. How can in do that, please help me.Below is my html tag for same.

```
<input id="kb_file" type="file" class="file" name="multipartFile" contenteditable='false' style="display:none;"/>
```

Comment: Browser security will not let you set the value of a file input.

Comment: No can do. Just leave it alone.

Comment: Why `display: none;`? are you trying to steal some files from your site visitors?

Comment: Since we have two option either choose file or write description.So i have used  display none.

Comment: Sorry, i was just joking.

Comment: @haim770 Personally I came here to attempt to automate testing of an image uploader widget (jQuery file upload), which is a valid reason to want to specify the file path of a test upload file.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot mess with the `value` of a `<input type="file" />` for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Yes i understand that. But Do we have any alternative to solve this issue.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? why do you need to access the value of `file` input?

Comment: 1st time when i create i uploaded the file and then when i edit same i want to append same file in that input field.

Comment: Check http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/, though i'm not quite sure it's related.

Comment: Why not reuse the originally uploaded file instead of uploading again?